# Xcode 6 GM, IB Challenge and Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm hoping someone can help me or even just let me know that I'm not going out of my mind. I have been searching for an answer to my issue for the past 4 hours and have tried many solutions, none seem to help.

My challenge is that I don't seem to be able to make use of a custom class for a view controller within the GM release of Xcode 6. Here is what I have done.

- Begin a new project using File -> New -> Project, selected for an iOS
  single view application to start. Once the initial application has
  been created, it runs fine within the simulator.
- Now I go into my `ViewController.swift` and change class
  `ViewController: UIViewController {` to class `ViewControllerxxx:

  UIViewController {`
- Next, I go into my `Main.Storyboard`, select the View Controller and
  drop down the custom list class where I do not see my custom class.

Now here is where is gets strange.

If I open a project that was created on an earlier beta build of Xcode, the above process works just fine and I see my custom class, just not with newly created projects.

Does anyone else see this behavior, or is it just me?

Hoping someone can shed some light for me...

BTW - manually defining the custom class name doesn't work either - I get a runtime error saying the class is unknown.

Many thanks in advance,
Jon

Comment: The drop down list show 5 or so classes, but it scrolls. Try scrolling down.  When I tried this, ViewControllerxxx was at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Yeah I did, its not there. I just installed the GM on my laptop and that doesn't exhibit the problem, just my desktop. Sooo i've removed Xcode and removed all files like Application Support etc - going to re-install and try again...

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that I have fixed it although I have no idea how or why. Basically all of my projects are stored in a folder \Users\jon\code. I renamed the code folder to code.old and then back to code again and for whatever reason, it works now without an issue. I have zero idea as to what caused this issue as nothing in the folder has changed, but the issue is certainly resolved, or at least it appears to be.

So to anyone else experiencing this issue. First try creating a project in a location different to where you are when experiencing the problem. For example, if you are creating your project in Documents, try creating it in the root of your home folder.

If this works, drop to a terminal and using the mv command, rename your projects folder to something else and then back again. After this, I was able to create as many new projects as I wanted, an none had the issue.

Hope this helps someone...